# EPiServer7 PageTypes not getting updated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver-7

I have a completely new EPi7 mvc4(Razor) solution. When I try to add a simple page type the DB is not getting updated. And there are no page types available

The page type looks like this:

```
[ContentType(DisplayName = "TestPage", GUID = "00e90ef5-cc85-487c-9aed-c28e6046cb2b", Description = "")]
public class TestPage : PageData
{
    [CultureSpecific]
    [Editable(true)]
    [Display(
        Name = "Main body",
        Description = "The main body will be shown in the main content area of the page, using the XHTML-editor you can insert for example text, images and tables.",
        GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
        Order = 1)]
    public virtual XhtmlString MainBody { get; set; }
}
```

Is there maybe some kind of switch like in previous versions to turn off sync? I'm aware of the fact the this is not a PageTypeBulder anymore but still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. This problem had it's source in badly named web project (xxx.Web.Mvc). When I removed the '.Mvc' part it started working. It's very strange. I didn't know that naming can break Epi7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an option to  turn off synchronization like in previous version of EPiServer.

You can disable the commit phase by setting **enableModelSyncCommit** to false on the **siteSettings** element in **episerver.config**.

> This can be useful if there are many developers working on a shared
>   database and you want to avoid a newly added property to be removed
>   from another piece of the code.

You can read more on blog about [synchronization of typed models](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Per-Bjurstrom/Archive/2012/10/Synchronization-of-typed-models/)